# Financial Charting Toolkit with support for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, toolkit, financial

I am working on StockChartX Component produced by Modulus Global, It's a great tool actually but unfortunately it is still quite complicated to enhance, add and modify any of its component for a custom behavior. I have been looking for a while now, but I couldn't find anything powerful enough. Can any one please tell me what is the best Financial Charting Tool with support for WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use OxyPlot... It has a lot of different modes